# interactive plot_ly() in R is empty

Tags: r, plotly

```
df <- data.frame(PC1=c(0.05,0.056,0.0256),PC2=c(1.025,0.256,-2.548),PC3=c(3.35,-2.458,-3.66))
fig <- plot_ly(df,type = 'scatter',mode = 'markers') 
fig
```

`fig` is empty. Why? I have already looked into here https://plotly.com/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your data contains three PCs, so it should be a 3D scatter plot. In your code, you have not specified x, y, z that's why the plot is coming empty. Use

```
library(plotly)
df <- data.frame(PC1=c(0.05,0.056,0.0256),PC2=c(1.025,0.256,-2.548),PC3=c(3.35,-2.458,-3.66))
fig <- plot_ly(df, x = ~PC1, y = ~PC2,  z = ~PC3) 
fig <- fig %>% add_markers()
fig
```

[image]